# Why is there a compile error using Tensorflow c++ api on mac?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, tensorflow

I have a question abount Tensorflow c++ API.
I would like to build cpp using Tensorflow c++ api by g++ on Mac.
　
**Install Tensorflow**

Tensorflow was installed by reading [install_mac](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) and [install_c](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c).
Then, I could build like below.

```
(tensorflow) > $ ./a.out
hello from tensorflow c library version 1.4.0-rc1
```

I could also build example.cc using C++ API by bazel on [api_guides](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_guides/cc/guide).

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"

int main() {
  using namespace tensorflow;
  using namespace tensorflow::ops;
  Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
  // Matrix A = [3 2; -1 0]
  auto A = Const(root, { {3.f, 2.f}, {-1.f, 0.f} });
  // Vector b = [3 5]
  auto b = Const(root, { {3.f, 5.f} });
  // v = Ab^T
  auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true));
  std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
  ClientSession session(root);
  // Run and fetch v
  TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({v}, &outputs));
  // Expect outputs[0] == [19; -3]
  LOG(INFO) << outputs[0].matrix<float>();
  return 0;
}
```

However, I would like to build this example.cc by g++.

Next, I've compiled [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow).

```
$ ./configure
...
$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
...
...
$ install -m 0644 bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.dylib
$ install -m 0644 bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so
$ install_name_tool -id /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.dylib
$ install_name_tool -id /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.dylib
```

Finally, I've collected include files to /usr/local/include/tensorflow/include/.

**run example.cpp by g++**

I've built example.cpp renamed from example.cc on the above this page.
Then, I ran into next error.

```
(tensorflow) > $ /usr/bin/g++ example.cpp -I/usr/local/include/tensorflow/include -L/usr/local/lib -ltensorflow_cc -std=c++11
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "tensorflow::TensorShapeBase<tensorflow::TensorShape>::TensorShapeBase(std::initializer_list<long long>)", referenced from:
      __ZN10tensorflow11TensorShapeCI2NS_15TensorShapeBaseIS0_EEESt16initializer_listIxE in example-4b6420.o
  "tensorflow::TensorShapeBase<tensorflow::TensorShape>::dims() const", referenced from:
      Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> tensorflow::TensorShape::AsEigenDSizesWithPadding<2>() const in example-4b6420.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**This is my Mac environment.**

1. macOS High Sieera version 10.13.1
2. (tensorflow) > $ /usr/bin/g++ --version
   Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
   Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0
   Thread model: posix
   InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
3. (tensorflow) > $ g++ --version
   g++ (Homebrew GCC 7.1.0) 7.1.0
   Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
4. python version: 3.5.2
5. tensorflow-1.4.0rc1
6. (tensorflow-1.4.0) > $ bazel version
   Build label: 0.7.0
   Build target: bazel-out/darwin_x86_64-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
   Build time: Wed Oct 18 14:25:46 2017 (1508336746)
   Build timestamp: 1508336746
   Build timestamp as int: 1508336746

   Do you have any idea?
   I would appreciate for your response.

Comment: You seem to install two different libraries, but you just refer to one of them in a `-l` option on the g++ command line. Could the missing parts perhaps be in the other library?

Comment: By Adding `-ltensorflow_framework` to above command line, It works perfectly. Thank you for the comment!